# Air iOS app iPhone5 dimensions letterbox

Tags: ios, air

I have an app designed and built for iPhone4 however the same app also works on iPhone5 however with the top/bottom letterbox effect. The headers and footers of the app are black (very dark blue actually) but the empty letterbox space is white so I was wondering if there is a way to make the top/bottom black so it is not that noticeable?

I don't really feel like modifying the app layout to suit the dimensions of the iPhone5 if there is a way to make them black.

Thanks

Comment: Apple won't accept an app unless it properly uses the full screen of the iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the stage (background) color with stage.color, see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, I set the stage background to black and added a quad to the original stage color to fill the space of the app not the space of the screen so yes, this worked thanks.